# How to override the superscript in \cite when using revtex4-2 with aip configuration

Tags: bibtex, citing, superscripts, revtex

I'm writing a document in `revtex4-2` using the `aip` class option. This makes all the citations become superscripts. However, sometimes I want to write phrases such as "As shown in Ref. 1", which means I would need to override the superscript command to avoid getting "As shown in Ref. ¹" instead. How can I do this? I would rather not define a new citation command if possible, but that is an acceptable solution.

I'm using bibtex, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I later found out that the [`revtex4-2` manual](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/auguide/auguide4-2.pdf) discusses the `\onlinecite` command, which does precisely what I desired and it is intended exactly for what I wanted to do.